# How to know which type of FirebaseUser logged in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

in my app, I given 2 options login with phone verification and login with google,
after successful login, how to know which type of FirebaseUser logged in.

is it phone_verification or Google Verification ?

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `providerData` from that user. The method bellow returns `true` if it's using phone or `false` if phone auth has not been found as a provider for that user.

```java
private boolean isPhoneAuth(FirebaseUser user) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
        if (providerId.equals("phone") {
            return true;
        }
        if (providerId.equals("google.com") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that this won't work if your app supports [Account Linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), because then the same user will be able to login with both Phone and Google Auth.